# How to find correlation between two values

Tags: correlation

I have a table with two columns emailid and keyword and I am pivoting(kind of matrix) the value is sql such as the columns are the distinct keywords and the rows are the distinct users the values at [emailid][keyword] is 1 if the value is present and null if it is not, and I am trying to find the correlation between keywords i.e. if two users have searched for the same keyword then there is a correlation between those two keywords, How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.  For starters, (1) provide a brief example of your data and desired result; (2) have this proofread by a friend who knows English; the lack of phrase markers and punctuation make this very hard to parse.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace the null value with 0 to begin. You may want to explore various correlation techniques such as Pearson and Spearman correlation.

This is a page on Pearson Correlation: http://learntech.uwe.ac.uk/da/Default.aspx?pageid=1442

```
from scipy.stats.stats import pearsonr
a =[1.0001345,0.000656];b=[1.00001345,0.000656]
print pearsonr(a,b)[0]
```

This gives the output as 1.0 which means total correlation or positive correlation. The output of Pearson correlation varies from -1.0 (Most negative correlation) to 1.0 (high positive correlation). Here 0 means no correlation between the two data quantity.

The more information on this could be found under:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html